# How to add two addDisplayGroup in Zend Decorators

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, decorator, zend-decorators

addDisplayGroup 1:

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(DATEFROM,ELEM_DATETO),
                      'Date', array('order'  => 4,
                                'decorators' => array('FormElements',

        array(array('openinnerdiv' => 'HtmlTag'),
              array('tag' => 'div', 'id'=>'date_to_from','name'=>'date_to_from','class'=>'date_to_from')),

         array(array('opendiv' => 'HtmlTag'),
         array('tag' => 'div','id'=>'date' ))                                       
             ),
        )
    );
```

addDisplayGroup 2:

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(array('AddBlock','Add','AddDate','ORDERID','COUNTRYCODE','DATEFROM','DATETO','AGE','GENDER','LIST','CAMERA'),
              'queryblockfld_1',array('order'    => 4,
                'decorators' => array('FormElements',

                array(array('openinnerdiv' => 'HtmlTag'),
                      array('tag' => 'div', 'id'=>'queryblockfld_1','name'=>'queryblockfld','class'=>'queryblockfld')),

                array(array('opendiv' => 'HtmlTag'),
                      array('tag' => 'div','id'=>'queryblock' ))

                                                                ), 
                                            )
                        );
```

I want to Add  `addDisplayGroup1` to `addDisplayGroup 2`.  Can any one help me in this.?

Comment: "I want to Add the form Element 1 to addDisplayGroup1 to addDisplayGroup 2" doesn't make sense. Please could you clarify your question?

Comment: @TimFountain Now I corrected my question

Comment: Ah, makes sense now! So you want a display group inside another display group?

Comment: Check out my answer if any thing wrong kindly correct it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research in Web I found the answer for my own question:

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(array('DATEFROM','DATETO'),
                                       'contact',array('legend' => 'Contact Information'));

$from_to = $this->getDisplayGroup('contact');
$from_to->setDecorators(array('FormElements',
  array(array('openinnerdiv' => 'HtmlTag'),
  array('tag' => 'div', 'id'=>'date_1','name'=>'date_1','class'=>'date_1','openOnly'=>true)),
  array(array('opendiv6' => 'HtmlTag'),
  array('tag' => 'div','id'=>'blockfld_1','class'=>'blockfld','openOnly'=>true)),
  array(array('opendiv' => 'HtmlTag'),
  array('tag' => 'div','id'=>'block','openOnly'=>true)),                                                                        
));


$this->addDisplayGroup(array('AddBlock','Add','AddDate','NUMBERPLATE','COUNTRYCODE','NODE','CAMERA','NODELIST','NODECAMERA'),
       'pass',array('legend' => 'Password')); 

$pass = $this->getDisplayGroup('pass');
 $pass->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',
         array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'div','closeOnly'=>true))
));
```

I just modified for the answer so some small mistakes will be there kindly correct it.